# Как настроить scrolledtext, чтобы при добавлении туда текста, скролл прокручивался вниз?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Вот функция при нажатии на кнопку:

```py
console1 = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(
    master = main_frame,
    wrap   = WORD,
    width  = 50,
    height = 12,
    state = 'disabled'
)

def sender_start():
    console1.configure(state='normal')
    console1.insert('end', 'Some Text\r\n')
    console1.configure(state='disabled')
```

Как сделать, чтобы при добавлении текста скролл спускался вниз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в функцию `sender_start` метод [see](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.see-method). Из документации

> Makes sure a given position is visible. If the index isn’t visible, scroll the view as necessary.

Т.е. с помощью данного метода мы убеждаемся, что указанная позиция видна на экране, в противном случае, будет автоматически осуществлён скролл до нужной позиции. В вашем случае нужно указать позицию `end`.

```
def sender_start():
    console1.configure(state='normal')
    console1.insert('end', 'Some Text\r\n')
    console1.configure(state='disabled')
    console1.see("end")
```